# Div acting as a form input (onclick)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a page which connects to a database where I have some users. Then, it takes each user and puts a div for each one of them, so I have 6 divs (a user in each div).

What I want is that, when somebody clicks in a div, it would give me the id of that user like if it was a form with an input.
I mean: the page takes the id and the name of each user from the database, so if I used a normal input, I would make that when the form is submitted, the form would return me the id of the selected user, but as I am using divs and no buttons, it would be nice to achieve that.

This is how my page looks (number 4 is where my mouse is):

[image: My page look]

The structure is basically, as I said, 6 divs, each one containing the name and the id of the user (I hide the names for privacy).

So, what can I do? If I haven't explained well I can give you more details... Thanks!!

Comment: Do you need a POST or a GET?

Comment: @putvande A POST would be preferable... Thanks!

Comment: You can create click event on the base of ur div id and in that make an ajax call to your server code and fetch the data and in success call of ur ajax display in div however you want

Comment: @Neel and how can I do this?

Comment: @Uriel_SVK Yes.. I thought about a `$("#divid").on("click", function()`, but I don't know what to put inside this onclick...

Comment: @peregraum Put a POST ajax request... Please consider to check the DOC, there are examples there:  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: @A.Wolff Okay, thanks for the example, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML should be generated similar to this (each div has an attribute to point to its corresponding user from the DB)

```
<form id="select-user" action="formActionPage.php" method="POST">
<input id="selected-user" type="hidden" value="0">
</form>

<div id="1" class="user"></div>
<div id="2" class="user"></div>
<div id="3" class="user"></div>
```

The form has no submit button as you mentioned but has an input which is hidden notice that value=0 is a default value chosen by me .. you may control this in the action page ..

JQuery:

```
$("div").on('click', function() {
    $('#selected-user').val($(this).attr('id'));
$('#select-user').submit();
});
```

EDIT
you may use div.[classname] div.user in my example, because you just don't want to apply this for any div

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

HTML code:

```
<div><span id='userId'>10</span></div>
<div><span id='userId'>11</span></div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$("div").on('click', function() {
    var userId = $("span", $(this)).text();
    console.log(userId);
});
```

CSS code:

```
span {
    display: none;
}
```

Main idea is to create in each div hidden span in which you will store user id, connected to this `div`. Also, you need `onclick` event, which will find this span and show needed id. Simple. Demo below.

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8q8xG/5/)

Note, that it is just an example. You can edit it as you need

Comment: why do that? you can just use `function(event)` and get to clicked object properties using `event` variable

Comment: @Uriel_SVK it is another way to do that. Improve my answer or create new one. I just suggested first way that had come to my mind.